# Missing a temporary folder not fixed

Tags: uploads, media

I uploaded my first wordpress website on the server, but trying to add new media files, i have got the message "Missing a temporary folder", I tried the solutions on the forum:

```
define('WP_TEMP_DIR',dirname(__FILE__).'/wp-content/temp/');
```

and created a 'temp' folder on 'wp-content', but the problem still happened ..
how to fix that please ??

I tried by doing this : creating the folder on localhost with writable property then upload it to the server, but it still doesn't work

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to add that line to your wp-config.php. Double check that you put it in the right place.
2. You need to set the permissions on that directory you created so that Wordpress can write to it. This is dependent on how your hosting works and what program you're using, but you should try setting the permissions to e.g. 770, which gives write permission to both the user and group.

Comment: I have already tried all this, the line is correct on the specific line, after the comment /* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing.*/ and i've changed the permissions, but nothing changed, i created 2 folders just in case, one 'temp' the other 'tmp', still not working

Comment: Did you change the permissions on the server? The permissions in your local system probably don't make any difference

Comment: I posted an image about permissions on the server, i notice that when I change group permissions to write on it doesn't keep it on, but I don't think this is the problem because I'm the only owner who manage the website, no need for group permissions.

Comment: That could be the problem...

Comment: but the server doesn't keep changes on group permissions, how can I fix that please ?

Comment: That would be a great question for your hosting company or server admin.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have accidentally deleted the **tmp** folder from my computer (Macbook) and faced the issue on the localhost WordPress site, and followed the below steps to fix the issue:

1. First, have to check the temporary folder location by the below code.

   `var_dump(sys_get_temp_dir());` In my case, the output was /var/tmp
2. Then, we have to check if the folder exists or not, by the below code.
   `var_dump(file_exists(sys_get_temp_dir()));` In my case, the folder did not exist as I already deleted that.
3. If the folder does not exist, then create a new folder named **tmp**.
   Open the terminal and navigate to the folder `/private/var` and create a new folder named **tmp**.
4. If the issue is not fixed yet, or the folder already exists then we have to check the permissions of the folder.